# Passing Parameters to an R Script via CMD or Batch

Tags: r, batch-file, parameters

Currently I have an R Script that takes 8 parameters that are hard-coded as the first 8 lines of my script.

I've made a Batch file to try and manually change the parameters on the fly, but it doesn't seem to be working the way I want it to.

**Batch that currently runs the script** (*But doesnt actually change the parameters*)

```
echo off
ECHO PRESS ENTER AT ANY INPUT TO ACCEPT the DEFAULT VALUE.

:: Setting of Variables
@Set /P RScript=Set path to R:_
@Set /P RProgram=Set path to RScript:_   
@Set /P RStartDir=Set Start Directory:_   
@Set /P Begin=Begin on which Loan?:_       
@Set /P End=End on which Loan?:_         
@Set /P OutputDir=Set Output Directory:_   
@Set /P Deal=Set Deal input file (.txt):_         
@Set /P OutputFile=Name Deal Output File:_
@Set /P AsOfDate=As of Date?:_  
@Set /P ThirtyYrSpread=Thirty Year Mortgage Spread?:_

:: If Blank (enter), set variables/paths to Defaults (Listed Below)

if "%RScript%"==""              Set RScript=c:\program files\r\r- 
3.4.3\bin\x64\rscript.exe
if "%RProgram%"==""             Set RProgram=C:\MortgageMatt\Cirt2014- 
1\0.Mortgage Model.R
if "%RStartDir%"==""            Set RStartDir=C:\MortgageMatt\Cirt2014-1
if "%Begin%"==""                Set Begin=1
if "%End%"==""                  Set End=2
if "%OutputDir%"==""            Set OutputDir=C:\MortgageMatt\Cirt2014-1
if "%Deal%"==""                 Set Deal=Cirt 2014-1 Loan Level.txt
if "%OutputFile%"==""           Set OutputFile=Cirt 2014-1d
if "%AsOfDate%"==""             Set AsOfDate=62017
if "%ThirtyYrSpread%" == ""     Set ThirtyYrSpread=135

echo "%RScript% %RProgram% %RStartDir% %Begin% %End% %OutputDir% %Deal% 
%OutputFile% %AsOfDate% %ThirtyYrSpread%"

ECHO PLEASE CHECK IF THESE VALUES ARE CORRECT
pause

:: Command Prompt, /c Carries out command specified by string and then 
terminates
cmd /c ""%RScript%" "%RProgram%" "%RStartDir%" "%Begin%" "%End%" 
"%OutputDir%" "%Deal%" "%OutputFile%" "%AsOfDate%" "%ThirtyYrSpread%""
```

So because the parameters were actually hard coded into the R Script, this is what I've added to try to accommodate. Does this look okay? I think this is where I'm running into errors.

**Added to R Script**

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
if (length(args) == 0) {
   if (!exists("dataDir")) { stop("variables dataDir not found") }
   # Set dataDir variable when Running inside a R Session
   args <- c(getwd(), 1, 2, ".", "Cirt 2014-1 Loan Level.txt", "Cirt 2014- 
    1", "62017", 175)
}
print(args)

# Input Values

Input.Directory <- paste(args[1]) ## getwd() , "/", "inputs", sep = "")
Begin.Sim <- args[2]
End.Sim <- args[3]
Output.Directory <- paste(args[1],"\\",args[4],sep = "") ##, "/", "outputs", 
sep = "")
Pool.ID.File <- args[5] #"Cirt 2014-1 Loan Level.txt"
Pool.ID <- args[6] #"Cirt 2014-1"
asofdate <- args[7] #"62017"
Thirty.Yr.Mort.Spread <- args[8] # 175
```

When I try to run it in cmd using the .bat.. I get an error that says cannot change working directory. Anyone have any suggestions?

I sort-of understand where the error is but I'm struggling to fix it.
The path to my file with everything in it is

```
C:\MortgageMatt\Cirt2014-1
```

Edit:

I've also heard of something called R CMD Batch... should I look into that? I'm finding that it's an older technique.

**What my code looked like before the Args/IF**

```
# Input Values
Input.Directory  <- "C:/Mortgage/Cirt 2014 - 1"
Output.Directory <- "C:/Mortgage/Cirt 2014 - 1"
Pool.ID.File     <- "Cirt 2014-1 Loan Level.txt"
Pool.ID <- "Cirt 2014-1 NEW"
start<- 1 
sims <- 2  # Number of Simulations
asofdate <- "62017"
Thirty.Yr.Mort.Spread <- 175
```

Comment: Are the variables already set to anything before the batch file runs? note that `set /P`, when just pressing enter, does not clear the variables but keeps the former value (and sets `ErrorLevel` to `1`); so you could define the defaults just before the `set /P` command block...

Comment: They were, in my previous version of the R code. That's why I tried to add that args, if statement. To see if that will instead read the input parameters from my Batch File.

Comment: So you abandoned the solution I gave you in your previous question on this same topic.

Comment: Let's discuss in that post, i responded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do all of this in R using one of these packages to parse command-line options:

- docopt (my favourite)
- optparse
- argparse
- getopt

or doing it manually -- not recommended.

You also do not want the older `R CMD BATCH` -- use Rscript (or littler,  but littler does not work on Windows).

#### Code Example

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

suppressMessages(library(docopt))

doc <- "Usage: foo.R [-h] [-x] [--src REPODIR] [--out OUTDIR] [FILES...]

-s --src REPODIR      source root directory [default: ~/git]
-o --out OUTDIR       output directory [default: /tmp]
-h --help             show this help text"

opt <- docopt(doc)          # docopt parsing

print(opt)
```

#### Use with -h

You get a nice message, *automatically*, with not formatting need:

```
edd@rob:/tmp$ Rscript so50256138.R -h
Usage: foo.R [-h] [-x] [--src REPODIR] [--out OUTDIR] [FILES...]

-s --src REPODIR      source root directory [default: ~/git]
-o --out OUTDIR       output directory [default: /tmp]
-h --help             show this help text 
edd@rob:/tmp$
```

#### Use with argument

Note how one default argument is used, and the other from the command-line:

```
edd@rob:/tmp$ Rscript so50256138.R -s A 
List of 9
 $ --src : chr "A"
 $ --out : chr "/tmp"
 $ --help: logi FALSE
 $ -x    : logi FALSE
 $ FILES : list()
 $ src   : chr "A"
 $ out   : chr "/tmp"
 $ help  : logi FALSE
 $ x     : logi FALSE
NULL
```

You can access them in `opt` by name or by option flag.

The [docopt](http://docopt.org/) site has more; this is actually a portable specification and the CRAN package implements it for R.

Comment: You're suggesting that docopt can completely replace my batch file?

Comment: Yes!  I do all of this with R scripts -- it is a richer programming language (to me) than shell, or powershell, or CMD, or ...  and consistent across OSs.  See the example I added.

Comment: Awesome, I'll process all of this and get back to you. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sure. Feel free to accept and/or upvote the answer.  There are other questions and answers for docopt here at SO as well.

Comment: In your opinion as well, do you think I need that if statement? Can I go back to having the input values hard-coded and then use Docopt on top of that? I posted what the first portion of my code looked like in the bottom part of my question.

Comment: If you have a fixed script with no variability, just encode that in Rscript. _Ultimately_, I have often found, we want to vary those which is why they are paremeters. And then docopt and the other packages are good, and I find docopt easiest to work with.

Comment: Okay got it. I want the ability to parameterize on the fly, so I'll delve deeper into Docopt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170703/discussion-between-matrixfox-and-dirk-eddelbuettel).

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/Rscript` is linux right? what's the equivalent for windows?